# Selenium::Remote::Driver capture errors

Tags: perl, selenium, error-handling

How does one go about capturing errors from [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/module/Selenium%3a%3aRemote%3a%3aDriver).
I understand that it shows remote driver response but it's a little confusing on how one implements this. 
I am currently using eval around my commands but is there a better way to capture the specific error?

[I'm a bit new to selenium for perl]

Answer (score 2):

No, that's already how one works with that module. It throws exceptions for every little thing that can go wrong (a design mistake in my book), so you have no other choice but to catch them. Perhaps switch to [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try%3a%3aTiny) if you want syntactic sugar.

Since the module errors are untyped strings (another design mistake), you cannot catch specific errors. You have to catch all and parse them.